# Do I need a Alternative Heatsink?

Tags: cpu, cooling, heatsink, intel-pentium

I have Intel [Pentium G2020](http://ark.intel.com/search?q=Pentium+G2020), it is not overclocked (i guess) but still should I bother getting [this](http://www.antecindia.co.in/product.php?id=NzA0NDE0) heatsink for my processor just so that my processor stays at room temperature while I am doing some heavy processor based stuff?

Comment: The stock Intel fan is enough to keep the CPU's temperature within the specifications of the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  If a CPU ships with a cooling solution then that one is usually good enough for a normal setup.

You only need to change/improve the cooling if you are doing non standard things. E.g. if you:

- Use the desktop in a very hot place where ambient temperatures are very high.
- Or when you overclock (and thus increase power used and heat generated on the CPU).
- Or it you want to use a less noisy solution.

But in general: no, no need to change. And the CPU is allowed to get hot (just not too hot). But under standard conditions it no change is needed.

Comment: thanks, you saved me some money but I am still worried about the lasting of my processor, I know that the processor doesn't get hot but it would be good if you gave me some advise to keep the CPU clean

Comment: Just one: use common sense. Air flow is a flow, so place fans to blow cold air in and warm air out (not all fans blowing out or all blowing in). Accasionally remove dust (rarely in a clean house, a bit more if you have a cat or other hair shadding pet). Nothing special. Just common sense.

Comment: well then, I am using my sense and I have decided to Attach a 120 mm Fan in front with air filter sucking air in and 2x 80 mm fan in back blowing air away and whole cabinet closed